# (React Component Tests) How to unit test if a function from a different module is called in componentDidMount using jasmine

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am writing unit tests for React Component. How to write a unit test to check if a function from different module gets called in componentDidMount in jasmine.
Here's my Component :

```js
import {differentModuleFunc} from "someModule";
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        differentModuleFunc();
    }

    render() {
        return 
            <div>
               TestDiv
            </div>;
    }
 }
```

My unit test for component looks like :

```js
describe("MyComponent", () => {
    it("differentModuleFunc should have been called", (done) => {
        const spy = spyOn(MyComponent, "differentModuleFunc");
        myComponentDiv = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent/>);
        expect(myComponentDiv).toBeDefined();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the function and then assert the call count. Using your example you can do the following:

```js
import {differentModuleFunc} from "someModule";
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        differentModuleFunc();
    }

    render() {
        return 
            <div>
               TestDiv
            </div>;
    }
 }
```

You import "someModule" in the test, mock it and then assert the call count.

```js
import {differentModuleFunc} from "someModule"; // import the function

jest.mock('someModule', () => ({ differentModuleFunc: jest.fn() })) // mocks the function

describe("MyComponent", () => {
    it("differentModuleFunc should have been called", (done) => {
        const spy = spyOn(MyComponent, "differentModuleFunc");
        myComponentDiv = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent/>);
        expect(myComponentDiv).toBeDefined();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(differentModuleFunc.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) // assert call count
    });
});
```